# Outlook 2013 search indexing set schedule

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, search-indexing

I have been routinely experiencing the search warning: "Search results might be incomplete because items are being indexed". Why is it that the search indexer can't just run at night, on a specific set schedule? When it runs during the day, I can't find any of my emails during normal business working hours.

Is there a way to schedule the search indexing process? Side note--I'm using an SSD, so is the indexing process even necessary? Should I just turn off the Windows search indexing process entirely?

Comment: Really? No way to schedule the search indexer process? Ridiculous!

Comment: How many e-mails do you have? How many new e-mail come per hour? How big is your documents directory? How much space is free on the SSD (what percentage is currently utilized)?

Comment: 500GB SSD with 65GB used space (13% utilization). About three years of emails... so, around 150,000 inbound and 90,000 outbound. I receive about 150 per day, and send about 90-150.

Comment: You can manually turn on/off with ```net stop wsearch``` or start of course. Easy to add that to a schedule but see the other comments. My question is whether it is actually the client side index that is the problem or a server-side index (MS Exchange)?

Comment: @Julian Knight So, unless I am mistaken, the solution would be to add a task that runs command-line: 1) "net stop wsearch", 2) "net start wsearch" every day at 1AM.

Comment: Yes, but as sunk818 says, are you really sure you understand the ramifications. You can stop and start whenever you link but I don't think it will help. Are you using Exchange?

Comment: Yes I'm using Exchange. I understand the ramifications. Just hate not being able to search my emails during normal working hours.

Comment: Do you need to search 240k emails every time you perform a search? How far back (date wise) do you typically need to search for the e-mail you need?

Comment: Not every time, but surely, often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Search is constantly indexing Outlook e-mails so your search results are up to date. If you run it once a night, then all your e-mails from the last index will not appear in search results. If you subscribe to Office 365, unindexed e-mails will be searched on the server and presented to you, but with some delay.

Some suggestions to minimize the message:

**Rebuild the index in case of data corruption:**

- Start
- Control Panels
- Indexing Options
- Advanced
- Rebuild

**Or Restart the Windows Search service.**

- Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools
- Double click Services
- Find Windows Search
- Right click Windows Search and select restart
- Close Services
- Wait a few seconds or minutes for the indexing to complete.

Source: http://michaelwlind.com/2013/04/03/outlook-stops-indexing/

**To Rebuild Windows Index via command line**

```
@echo off
net stop wsearch
del "%programdata%\microsoft\search\data\applications\windows\Windows.edb.bak"
move "%programdata%\microsoft\search\data\applications\windows\Windows.edb" "%programdata%\microsoft\search\data\applications\windows\Windows.edb.bak"
net start wsearch
```

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/rebuild-windows-7-search-index-via-command-line/21efe850-b5e5-426e-89e1-b696997810e5

Comment: I am aware that it runs constantly to add new emails to the index, but why there would be 4-6hr periods of time where this message appears in place of ANY results whatsoever, is beyond me. My hope was that if I rebuilt the full index every night that this would eliminate the issue entirely.

Comment: To confirm, this is a Microsoft Exchange Office365 email account. But when I click to "see more results from the server", there is a huge lag, so it's a useless fallback.

Comment: To the heart of the question, your message above under heading "Rebuild the index..."... can this be built into the Windows task scheduler to rebuild the full index every night while I am sleeping, and not while I am working?

Comment: Added the bit about rebuilding the Windows Index via command line thanks to @JulianKnight. Please talk to your Exchange Admin about setting about online archiving. We get 50GB of online archive as part of our Office 365 subscription. This is a separate box that group policy archives for anything older than 90 days. I can search both using search "All Mailboxes", but 99% of the time I use "Current Mailbox" which is the last 90 days. Your e-mail will only grow and you need an archive process to keep the "Current Mailbox" index a reasonable size for performance issues. This will keep you happier.

Comment: thank you. Also, to be clear, we used to use the archiving feature, but it just made the process even more inefficient because when I need to find something buried deep, and it's in the archive, it's impossible to find. This solution should cover it!! Thanks!

Comment: If that is what you're going to do... at least use the clean-up feature in Outlook 2013 to consolidate your threads. This will create fewer emails leading to faster search times and shorter indexing times. In the long run though, you really need a solution that scales. I don't know what e-mails you have, but having that many to search just seems absurd.

Comment: Already using that feature but good call.